# Merging dataframe with its sub dataframe in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 dataframes

the first is df_my that looks like this

```
     Seq   Grp    Lvl   Distance
0    1     A       1    71
1    2     A       2    50
2    3     F       1    35
...
19   20    A       1    68
20   21    C       3    25
```

The 2nd dataset is df_Out

```
     Seq   Grp    Lvl   Distance
1    2     J       9    50
2    3     K       6    35
...
20   21    S       8    25
```

All records with the same Seq in df_Out are in df_My

except Seq for records with Disance > 55

I want to put these 2 dataframes together considering

If record (Seq) in df_Out then it is the to be in my final dataframe

If record (Seq) is not in df_Out but in df_My then the one from df_My is in the final data frame

df_Final will be

```
     Seq   Grp    Lvl   Distance
0    1     A       1    71
1    2     J       9    50
2    3     K       6    35
...
19   20    A       1    68
20   21    S       8    25
```

How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach could be to [`append`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html) first dataframe (**df_my**) into second (**df_Out**) and then [`remove duplicates`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) by keeping the row from the second dataframe (**df_Out**).

```
df_Out.append(df_my).drop_duplicates(['Seq'], keep='first').sort_values('Seq')
```

Comment: you shouldn't use `DataFrame.append` anymore. It has been deprecated. Check [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/whatsnew/v1.4.0.html#whatsnew-140-deprecations-frame-series-append) for details.

Comment: Yes, You are right. Better use concat.

Answer (score 0):

It should work if you concat them and then drop duplicates, keeping the first:

```py
pd.concat([df_out, df_my]).drop_duplicates(subset='Seq', keep='first').sort_index()
```

Output:

```
    Seq Grp  Lvl  Distance
0     1   A    1        71
1     2   J    9        50
2     3   K    6        35
19   20   A    1        68
20   21   S    8        25
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to compose the algorithm of the commands that you just described.

1. calculate the set of values of Seq that are covered by `dataframe 2`, because you base your decision on which dataframe to use in the merge on this criteria
2. join the mutually exclusive (w.r.t. values of Seq column) subsets of  `dataframe 1` and `dataframe 2`
3. sort if necessary

Code (not teseted):

```
import numpy as np
seq_values_that_present_in_both_dfs_arr = np.intersect1d(df1['Seq'].unique(), df2['Seq'].unique())
result_df = pd.concat([df1.query('Seq not in @seq_values_that_present_in_both_dfs_arr'),
                       df2.query('Seq     in @seq_values_that_present_in_both_dfs_arr')]).reset_index().sort_values(by=[' Seq'])
```

I prefer to be explicit with what I want from the result in the code, than rely on obscure implementations of certain commands.